# Utilizar Python para executar testes no TFS

Tags: python-3.x, team-foundation-server, selenium-webdriver

Olá! Gostaria de saber como utilizar o Python para executar testes no TFS. Minha intenção seria gerar um script via Selenium WebDriver, transformar o código em Python e utilizá-lo no TFS para executar testes automatizados.

Consigo fazer isso com o código em C#, utilizando packages como o NUnit e Selenium, mas acho o Python uma linguagem muito mais simples do que o C#!

O mais próximo que encontrei na internet a respeito foram os sites abaixo:

http://www.techbeamers.com/selenium-webdriver-python-tutorial/#toc
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneOfMicrosoftsBestKeptSecretsPythonToolsForVisualStudioPTVS.aspx

Já consegui instalar o PTVS 2.2 Visual Studio 2013, mas ainda preciso saber quais são as packages necessárias para utilizar as bibliotecas corretamente, entre outros.

Alguém tem algum conhecimento sobre isso?

[]s

Comment: Só pra deixar claro: essa pergunta não é fora do escopo do site. Ela só não está entendível e o pouco que dá pra entender, mostra uma pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: "Gostaria de saber como utilizar o Python para executar testes no TFS." Esta é minha pergunta, resumidamente. O que devo instalar, quais packages utilizar... qualquer informação é válida.